# TPM 2 simulation with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, device-manager, tpm

I have an [Asus Hero XI wifi](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-xi-hero-wi-fi-model/) with a [9900k](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/186605/intel-core-i99900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html) but I never installed any TPM 2.0 chip (I confirm, there are no installed TPM 2.0 chip).
I remarked that device manager is showing since a while a TPM 2.0 device:

[image: TPM 2.0 device].

With tpm.msc, I remark that there is a TPM hardware:

[image: tpm module]

and is seems that INTC is Intel:

[image: INTC]

Why or how did it appear(*) ? to what hardware does this correspond to ? is this equivalent to an actual TPM 2.0 chip ?

(*) when W11 was released, I had confirmation that I had no TPM 2.0 chip and therefore I could not install it, but few days ago this changed without hardware change.

Comment: "Why or how did it appear ?" - The only method outside a physical TPM is if your CPU supports fTPM.

Comment: @Ramhound You should make this an answer. The Z390 chipset (as used on this board) supports the Intel Platform Trust Technology.

Comment: @DanielB - Only after the author confirms they don't actually have a physical TPM and they [edit] their question to indicate what processor they have. I have my doubts about the accuracy of the information in the question.

Comment: everything 6th gen intel onwards and non chinese market ryzen 3rd gen onwards (they have the support but MAY be disabled in firmware) ought to have an embedded TPM in it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Haswell (4th) supports fTPM but the ASUS motherboard does not, specifically, the firmware offered no way to enable it. But that doesn’t seem relevant in this case if it’s enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Windows 11 was released, I had confirmation that I had no TPM 2.0 chip and, therefore, I could not install it, but a few days ago, this changed without hardware change.

The most likely explanation is you enabled Intel Platform Trust Technology within your firmware settings. Intel Platform Trust Technology isn't a simulation of a TPM a more accurate description would be a persistent virtualization, but in reality, the capability is hardware supported within the processor itself.

> is this equivalent to an actual TPM 2.0 chip?

Intel Platform Trust Technology is equivalent to fTPM. fTPM is AMD's implementation of a firmware-based implementation (processor) of a TPM. BitLocker treats a physical and firmware TPM identically, there is no difference, in both cases for Windows 11 it would be the same functional implementation of TPM.

> Why or how did it appear(*) ? to what hardware does this correspond to?

It corresponds to Intel Platform Trust Technology